# Delay between XMLHttpRequest.load and XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange events

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache

The code below experiences a 40sec. delay **between** the occurence of the `load` event, which indicates that a 10MB `formdata` has been sent to the server and the `onreadystatechange` event, which indicates that some response from the server has been received.

```
function SendData(formdata) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        console.log('Finished Transmitting Formdata to Server');
    }, false);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e)    
    {
         console.log('XHR State Changed');

         if ( (xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200) )
            console.log('Server Replied with Success');
    }

    xhr.open("POST", "receive.php");
    xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

The `receive.php` file contains just:

```
<?php
   echo 'Formdata received Successfully';
?>
```

**Q**: What could be the cause of such long delay - why the console logs the `'XHR State Changed'` message a whopping 40sec. after logging the `'Finished Transmitting Formdata to Server'` message, ...and what are the proper troubleshooting steps to find out the exact cause of this delay ?

The delay occurs before `xhr.readyState == 2` which is before `HEADERS_RECEIVED`.

The `Network` tab of Chrome's DeveloperTools displays the following for the `receive.php`, ( type: `xhr` ):

```
Queueing:         2.08ms
Stalled:          0.62ms
Request sent:     894ms
Waiting (TTFB):   41.27s
Content Download: 0.69ms
```

P.S.
*PHP version: 7.1.33

Apache/N-G-I-N-X-htaccess-support

FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p3*

Comment: well 10MB is a decent amount to transfer, if the connection isn't so fast, or if the server doesn't have much bandwidth. Try to break the request/response down into steps. There's the sending of the data. Then the server must process it. Then it must return a response. If all the server does is echo, then it seems reasonable to think that the delay is due to the volume of data. Your browser's Network tools can help break it down - the ones in Chrome can give you detailed breakdown of the timing - how much time spent sending, then time waiting for a response, and time downloading the response

Comment: @ADyson: Are you suggesting that the `xhr.load` event is fired BEFORE the data is sent to the Server ?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure.  That's why you need to use the tools. Looking at your network tool might help you rule that in or out as a possibility. Especially if you get the console to log the exact time when the upload starts, and when the event occurs, so you can compare. And you'll also be able to see if there is a long waiting time for the server to respond, or not. In Chrome's Dev tools, go to the Network section, click on your ajax request and then click the "Timing" tab for that request.

Comment: P.S. Here's the documentation explaining what each phase in that section of the timing tab means: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing-explanation

Comment: @ADyson:  I verified with Wireshark, that the `load` event is fired only **after** 10.2MB is transferred over the wire...so the remaining question remains: "*Why it takes the server so long to process a 10MB of data?*".  How can I find out whether it is virus-scanning the received data, ...or doing other unwanted processing ?

Comment: Can you double check it with the tools as I asked please? I'm not familiar with how wireshark logs things. But yes it does sound odd.

Comment: Does the server take that long to respond if you send a 1kb file? Or send no upload at all but just submit the request? There's nothing intrinsically odd about your server setup from the basic details given. AFAIK Apache does not do automatic virus scanning or anything like that - within the HTTP request the file is just binary data, it won't even be scannable at that point anyway. Do you have any other environment you could test the same code on?

Comment: @ADyson:  The delay is proportional to the size of the `formdata`.  Sending the 10MB to the server, takes less than a second, so it is not a matter of internet connection.  The received data must get stored on the server, or it would become lost. How to find out what takes so long to process this received data?

Comment: Your internet connection. But still yours is fast enough compared to internet connections in our country.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson ok. So potentially some delay in ingesting the data. Please, for my benefit, check with the dev tools...does the delay come in the "Request sent", "Waiting" or "content download" phase?

Comment: "The received data must get stored on the server, or it would be lost"...no, because your PHP doesn't do anything with it. It gets held in memory temporarily, until the request ends. PHP _might_ hold it in a file in the /tmp folder on disk during that time (depending on config). So that could be a bottleneck...but no disk is that slow these days. Is the server very busy with other things? It would be good to test it on a clean environment.

Comment: @ADyson:  The delay occurs before `xhr.readyState == 2` which is `HEADERS_RECEIVED`

Comment: @ADyson:  The server storing the data in `RAM` or in a `tmp file` after reception, is what I meant by "must get stored on the server".  The server is a shared server but the delay is the same at 3am as at noon.  It looks like it is doing some unwanted processing on this data, e.g. virus scanning, but how to ascertain the exact cause of this long processing? Are there any configuration settings that would reveal it?

Comment: "The delay occurs before xhr.readyState == 2 which is HEADERS_RECEIVED". Ok. But that wasn't _quite_ the information I asked for. Do you understand what I'm requesting and where to find it?

Comment: You would be better to ask the hosting company if they do any incoming processing of data like that. But I'd be surprised if it's virus scanning. Not impossible though, but  that's a pretty naff service if it slows you down that much. I don't know of anything built into plain old Apache which would do that...it might be some extra module or something. Or the server could just be badly configured.

Comment: Queuing: 2.08ms  
Stalled: 0.62ms  
Request sent: 894ms  
Waiting (TTFB): 41.27s  
Content Download: 0.69ms

Comment: Ok good. That confirms it for me. Thankyou. Next, try sending it to a URL which isn't a PHP script. It needs to exist (just so you don't get immediate 404) but maybe just a plain HTML page. It won't process the response, but it might help to narrow down where the delay is - the request will just be processed by Apache, but not by the PHP interpreter, so it will hopefully show inside which of those two the delay occurs

Comment: I sent it to a plain HTML page without a PHP script in it ...and the delay after upload is still there.

Comment: ok so something at either the host's gateway or in apache is delaying it. But we really have very little idea what it could be. I think you need support from the hosting company, they will know how their stuff is set up. It'll probably help if you can demonstrate to them that it's not your code (i.e. deploy it somewhere else on a similar environment (even a virtual machine you create on your desktop would be a reasonable way) and show that it doesn't suffer the delay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay was caused by Apache's "Web Application Firewall" module, also known as "WAF".
Disabling this module removed the delay immediately.